# I want to edit a page element that's loaded from an external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kayako sideloads a chat messenger almost after the page has finished loading. What is the best way to edit the css styling for anything loaded within this chat messenger?

For example, open visakhi.kayako.com and after a couple of seconds, it will load the chat messenger at the bottom right corner. If you open the messenger, it has a button which says "start a conversation", how can I edit the font or add custom css style for this element?

Comment: Please show us some code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

for example

```js
   $('.edit-messenger-btn').click(function(){
      $('.messenger-btn').css('font-family' , 'sans-serif').css('font-weight', 'bold').css('color', 'red');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
   <button class="messenger-btn">start a conversation</button>
   <button class="edit-messenger-btn">edit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this - add following code to a webpage : https://codeshare.io/5Qd4pw

Comment: but anything I add to my webpage doesn't seem to apply to Messenger elements